# Difference between case object and object

Tags: scala

Is there any difference between case object and object in scala?

Comment: He has a point - it's not necessary to have a case object in order to be able to pattern match on it. I think this wasn't addressed in the previous question...

Comment: I thought there would be a difference in pattern matching behaviour but both a case object and a normal object behave the same way in a pattern match AFAIK. It's pretty hard to find any information at all about case objects so I'm looking forward to someone enlightening us.

Comment: It is not necessary to use `case` to have pattern matching, it is just sugar. Implementing `unapply` yourself does the job.

Comment: The accepted answer just doesn't answer the question, as discussed in the comments on it.  Way too late to make a difference, but should be noted.

Comment: It's not too late to edit the accepted answer. The edit will be reviewed and if relevant, accepted.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Case classes differ from regular classes in that they get:

1. pattern matching support
2. default implementations of `equals` and `hashCode`
3. default implementations of serialization
4. a prettier default implementation of `toString`, and
5. the small amount of functionality that they get from automatically inheriting from `scala.Product`.

Pattern matching, equals and hashCode don't matter much for singletons (unless you do something really degenerate), so you're pretty much just getting serialization, a nice `toString`, and some methods you probably won't ever use.

Comment: Having pattern matching makes a lot of sense if `case` is used in the "proper" use case: providing several implementations of one abstract class or trait. Some might be classes, some might be singleton objects.

Comment: Sure, but that works just as well for case objects as non-case objects.

Comment: Point 3 and 4 of this answer is correct difference between case objects and objects. Point 1 and 2 doesn't matter for singleton objects. And singleton objects are always Products with arity 0 so point 5 doesn't matter also.

Comment: This post perpetuates the myth that `object` is the same as a singleton. It is not. Rather it is exactly what it says it is, an object, i.e. a declaration and instantiation in one. This limits `object` to a single instance if defined in package scope, which effectively makes it a singleton, but only if defined IN THAT SCOPE. If defined inside a class, you can have as many instances as the class itself (it's lazily instantiated, so it's not necessarily 1-1). And those inner objects may very well be used as hash keys, making default equals/hashCode very much sensible.

Comment: The question is about `case object` not class, why is this the correct answer?

Comment: This does not answer the question. This answer deals with the difference between `case class` and a `class`. The question is about the difference between `case object` and `object`.

Comment: Because the list of differences between case classes and classes IS the list of differences between case object and object.

Comment: @C4stor The answer doesn't say that, though.  An object is not a class.  Given that case classes do a fair amount of magic behind the scenes, given Scala's various edge cases and complications, there's no reason simply to assume that the only difference between a standard Scala object and a case object is explained by what we know about the difference between standard classes and case classes.   This answer doesn't even address the wording of the question.

Comment: In fact, some things behave differently for case objects than regular instances of case classes.  Pattern matching behaves differently, for one thing.  So the answer isn't even accurate.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question!

Comment: This is not the right answer it's about case class vs class difference

Answer (score 148):

Here's one difference - case objects extend the `Serializable` trait, so they can be serialized. Regular objects cannot by default:

```
scala> object A
defined module A

scala> case object B
defined module B

scala> import java.io._
import java.io._    

scala> val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream                                            
bos: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream =  

scala> val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)                                          
oos: java.io.ObjectOutputStream = java.io.ObjectOutputStream@e7da60                   

scala> oos.writeObject(B)

scala> oos.writeObject(A)
java.io.NotSerializableException: A$
```

Comment: I think that case objects can be serialized is the most difference from regular objects especially in the network communication between actors

Comment: Adding `extends Serializable` should do the same trick though.

Answer (score 40):

```
scala> object foo
```

> defined object foo

```
scala> case object foocase
```

> defined object foocase

**Serialization difference:**

```
scala> foo.asInstanceOf[Serializable]
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: foo$ cannot be cast to scala.Serializable
>    ... 43 elided

```
scala> foocase.asInstanceOf[Serializable]
```

> res1: Serializable = foocase

**toString difference:**

```
scala> foo
```

> res2: foo.type = foo$@7bf0bac8

```
scala> foocase
```

> res3: foocase.type = foocase

Answer (score 3):

A huge necro, but it is the highest result for this question in Google outside official tutorial which, as always, is pretty vague about the details. Here are some bare bones objects:

```
object StandardObject

object SerializableObject extends Serializable

case object CaseObject
```

Now, lets use the very useful feature of IntelliJ 'decompile Scala to Java' on compiled .class files:

```
//decompiled from StandardObject$.class
public final class StandardObject$ {
   public static final StandardObject$ MODULE$ = new StandardObject$();

   private StandardObject$() {
   }
}

//decompiled from StandardObject.class
import scala.reflect.ScalaSignature;

@ScalaSignature(<byte array string elided>)

public final class StandardObject {
}
```

As you can see, a pretty straightforward singleton pattern, except for reasons outside the scope of this question, *two* classes are generated: the static `StandardObject` (which would contain static forwarder methods should the object define any) and the actual singleton instance `StandardObject$`, where all methods defined in the code end up as instance methods. Things get more intresting when you implement `Serializable`:

```
//decompiled from SerializableObject.class
import scala.reflect.ScalaSignature;

@ScalaSignature(<byte array string elided>)
public final class SerializableObject {
}

        //decompiled from SerializableObject$.class
import java.io.Serializable;
import scala.runtime.ModuleSerializationProxy;

public final class SerializableObject$ implements Serializable {
   public static final SerializableObject$ MODULE$ = new SerializableObject$();

   private Object writeReplace() {
      return new ModuleSerializationProxy(SerializableObject$.class);
   }

   private SerializableObject$() {
   }
}
```

The compiler doesn't limit itself to simply making the 'instance' (non-static) class `Serializable`, it adds a `writeReplace` method. `writeReplace` is an alternative to `writeObject`/`readObject`; what it does, it serializes *a different object* whenether the `Serializable` class having this method is being serialized. On deserializention then, that proxy object's `readResolve` method is invoked once it is deserialized. Here, a `ModuleSerializableProxy` instance is serialized with a field carrying the `Class[SerializableObject]`, so it knows what object needs to be resolved. The `readResolve` method of that class simply returns `SerializableObject` - as it is a singleton with a parameterless constructor, scala `object` is always structurally equal to itself between diffrent VM instances and different runs and, in this way, the property that only a single instance of that class is created per one VM instance is preserved. A thing of note is that there is a security hole here: no `readObject` method is added to `SerializableObject$`, meaning an attacker can maliciously prepare a binary file which matches standard Java serialization format for `SerializableObject$` and a separate instance of the 'singleton' will be created.

Now, lets move to the `case object`:

```
//decompiled from CaseObject.class
import scala.collection.Iterator;
import scala.reflect.ScalaSignature;

@ScalaSignature(<byte array string elided>)
public final class CaseObject {
   public static String toString() {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.toString();
   }

   public static int hashCode() {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.hashCode();
   }

   public static boolean canEqual(final Object x$1) {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.canEqual(var0);
   }

   public static Iterator productIterator() {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.productIterator();
   }

   public static Object productElement(final int x$1) {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.productElement(var0);
   }

   public static int productArity() {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.productArity();
   }

   public static String productPrefix() {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.productPrefix();
   }

   public static Iterator productElementNames() {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.productElementNames();
   }

   public static String productElementName(final int n) {
      return CaseObject$.MODULE$.productElementName(var0);
   }
}

        //decompiled from CaseObject$.class
import java.io.Serializable;
import scala.Product;
import scala.collection.Iterator;
import scala.runtime.ModuleSerializationProxy;
import scala.runtime.Statics;
import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.;

public final class CaseObject$ implements Product, Serializable {
   public static final CaseObject$ MODULE$ = new CaseObject$();

   static {
      Product.$init$(MODULE$);
   }

   public String productElementName(final int n) {
      return Product.productElementName$(this, n);
   }

   public Iterator productElementNames() {
      return Product.productElementNames$(this);
   }

   public String productPrefix() {
      return "CaseObject";
   }

   public int productArity() {
      return 0;
   }

   public Object productElement(final int x$1) {
      Object var2 = Statics.ioobe(x$1);
      return var2;
   }

   public Iterator productIterator() {
      return .MODULE$.typedProductIterator(this);
   }

   public boolean canEqual(final Object x$1) {
      return x$1 instanceof CaseObject$;
   }

   public int hashCode() {
      return 847823535;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return "CaseObject";
   }

   private Object writeReplace() {
      return new ModuleSerializationProxy(CaseObject$.class);
   }

   private CaseObject$() {
   }
}
```

A lot more is going on, as `CaseObject$` now implements also `Product0`, with its iterator and accessor methods. I am unaware of a use case for this feature, it is probably done for consistency with `case class` which is always a product of its fields. The main practical difference here is that we get `canEqual`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods for free. `canEqual` is relevant only if you decide to compare it with a `Product0` instance which is not a singleton object, `toString` saves us from implementing a single simple method, which is useful when case objects are used as enumeration constants without any behaviour implemented. Finally, as one might suspect, `hashCode` returns a constant, so it is the same for all VM instances. This matters if one serializes some flawed hash map implementation, but both standard java and scala hash maps wisely rehash all contents on deserialization, so it shouldn't matter. Note that `equals` is not overriden, so it is still reference equality, and that the security hole is still there. A huge caveat here: if a case object inherit `equals`/`toString` from some supertype other than `Object`, the corresponding methods are not generated, and the inherited definitions are used instead.

TL;DR: the only difference that matters in practice is the `toString` returning the unqualified name of the object.

I must make a disclamer here, though: I cannot guarantee that the compiler doesn't treat case objects specially in addition to what is actually in the bytecode. It certainly does so when patterm matching case classes, aside from them implementing `unapply`.

Answer (score 2):

It's similar with `case class` and `class` ,we just use `case object` instead of `case class` when there isn't any fields representing additional state information.

Answer (score 2):

case objects implicitly come with implementations of methods toString, equals, and hashCode, but simple objects don't.
case objects can be serialized while simple objects cannot, which makes case objects very useful as messages with Akka-Remote.
Adding the case keyword before object keyword makes the object serializable.

Answer (score 1):

We know objects and "case class" before. But "case object" is a mix of both i.e it is a singleton similar to an object and with a lot of boilerplate as in a case class. The only difference is that the boilerplate is done for an object instead of a class.

case objects won't come with the below ones:

Apply, Un-apply methods. 
here are no copy methods since this is a singleton.
No method for structural equality comparison.
No constructor as well.