# Why `Nil` is defined as `case object`

Tags: list, scala, case, null

In scala source, I found:

```
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
    ...
}
```

I can't understand why it is declared as `case object` rather than `object`?

I found this question [ [Difference between case object and object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270752/difference-between-case-object-and-object) ] is useful, and I guess this reason is the key:

> default implementations of serialization

because we often send list of data to another actor, so Nil must be serializable, right?

---

With the provided answers(thanks), I try to write some code to verify it:

```
trait MyList[+T]

object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing]

val list: MyList[String] = MyNil

list match {
  case MyNil => println("### is nil")
  case _ => println("### other list")
}
```

You can see `MyNil` is not `case object`, but I can still use it in pattern matching. Here is the output:

```
### is nil
```

Do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 5):

In general for immutable data, the question should never be "why is this a case object (or class)" but rather "Can I make this a case object?".  With a few small exceptions (mostly due to inheritance), data elements in Scala should be immutable, and should be implemented via case classes/objects.  Given that, implementing Nil and :: as a case object and case class (respectively) is just standard practice, for which there is no downside.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments of that linked question, one thing you get is a prettier `.toString` result

```
scala> MyNil.toString
res0: String = MyNil$@51aa572b

scala> case object MyNil2 extends MyList[Nothing]
defined module MyNil2

scala> MyNil2.toString
res2: String = MyNil2

scala> Nil.toString
res1: String = List()
```