# Why does Scala have a case object?

Tags: scala

It cannot be initialized with params and it will only be compared with itself (singleton). So no advantage for its equals and hash code function. Has anyone come across a case where they find it useful?

Comment: "Has anyone come across a CASE where...". Heh. I chuckled.

Comment: It's useful when you want to define an algebraic datatype : https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/functional-scala-algebraic-datatypes-enumerated-types/

Comment: For example: `None` is `case object`. Actually, you use case objects when some instance of your `algebraic datatype` should be distinguished but has no any parameters. Like `Option`, `Some(v)` is `case class`, but `None` is just `None` without state. For why `case` is useful see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270752/difference-between-case-object-and-object

Comment: There are lot of case objects used in `akka` as message, like `PoisonPill` , `Tick`, and so on.

Comment: @dmitry please add it as an answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use *case objects* as an alternative for enumerations.

Details can be found here: [Case objects vs Enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1898932/2390083)

---

A simplified example from that question:

```
sealed trait Currency {
  def name: String
  def symbol: String
}

case object EUR extends Currency {
  val name = "EUR"
  val symbol = "€"
}

case object USD extends Currency {
  val name = "USD"
  val symbol = "$"
}
```

### Advantages

- This way there can be more fields (compared to ID and name in an `Enumeration`)
- The compiler warns (in case of a `sealed` type hierarchy), if a match is not exhaustive.

So this code

```scala
val ccy: Currency = EUR
ccy match {
  case EUR =>
    println("Euro")
}
```

will result in

> Warning:(27, 7) match may not be exhaustive.
>   It would fail on the following inputs: USD
>         ccy match {

### Disadvantages

- There is no "get by name" method (`Enumeration` provides `withName()`)
- You cannot iterate over "all" elements

Answer (score 5):

I think the most important difference is that *case objects* can be serialized while simple *objects* cannot.

This makes them very useful as messages with Akka-Remote.

**EDIT:**
As [Rüdiger Klaehn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2083327/r%C3%BCdiger-klaehn) pointed out, this is not the only benefit we get from the `case` keyword. There is also:

- hashCode implementation
- a useful toString implementation

For classes additionally:

- pattern matching optimization
- a companion object with useful `apply` and `unapply` implementations

(This list may not be exhaustive!)

Comment: A case object will also have hashCode and toString implemented. So `case object Foo; foo.toString` will give just Foo, whereas `object Foo; Foo.toString` will give something like Foo$@1bb485e7 (different at each run!). Same for hashCode: the hashCode of a case object will be the same in different JVM processes.

Comment: wait a case keyword will not make the class serializable right?

Comment: @Dragonborn On the contrary: The case keyword makes a class/object `Serializable` (amongst other things).

Comment: @Dragonborn even in scala 2.10.4 a `case class` is serializable. At least you can serialize instances of a `case class` with `java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`.