# Scala case class vs Kotlin data class

Tags: scala, class, kotlin

Scala has a feature called **case class**, while Kotlin has another feature called **data class**.
Which are the main differences between Scala **case class** and Kotlin **data class**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overall they are very similar, but there are some differences I'd mention:

1. Scala case class can have multiple parameter lists (including implicit parameters), and only parameters from the first list are used for `toString`/`equals`/`hashCode`.
2. Scala allows a case class to have no parameters, Kotlin doesn't. Of course, *usually* such a case class should be an `object` instead.
3. On that note, [`case object`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270752/difference-between-case-object-and-object) exist.
4. The companion object of a case class extends the corresponding function type by default.

Comment: Kotlin 1.9.10 finally added `data object` support

Answer (score 7):

Scala ***case class*** creates a class which:

1. Defines accessor functions (getters and setters basically)
2. Overrides naturally **hashcode**, **toString** and **equals** functions
3. Provides a **copy** function in order to create in an easy way shallow copies.

Kotlin **data class** does pretty much the same thing as Scala **case class**:

1. Defines accessor functions (getters and setters basically)
2. Overrides naturally **hashcode**, **toString** and **equals** functions
3. Provides a **copy** function in order to create in an easy way shallow copies.

The main differences between the two is the fact that Scala provides a more powerful pattern matching feature compared to Kotlin (in fact Kotlin doesn't have real pattern matching).